# Spring Can't register converter

Tags: string, spring, hashmap, converters

I'm following the example [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/validation.html#core-convert). 
My applicationContext has the following:

```
<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.mypackage.MyFilterConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My converter looks like this:

```
public class MyFilterConverter implements Converter<String, HashMap<String, List<MyClass>>> { ...
```

My problem: when I

```
@Autowired
private ConversionService conversionService;
```

and try to use it, the conversionService has only the default ones, not MyFilterConverter.

I followed the stack trace down to

```
GenericConversionService.addConverter(GenericConverter converter)
```

When I come back from this call, my converter is not added.

Any ideas?

thanks

--
llappall

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` to configure Spring MVC then it creates a conversionService internally and may be overriding your conversionService, the way to override is to replace `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` with this(if you are using Spring 3.1):

```
<bean name="handlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="webBindingInitializer">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.bind.support.ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer">
            <property name="conversionService" ref="conversionService"></property>
            <property name="validator">
                <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.XmlAwareFormHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"></bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This should ensure that only 1 conversionService(yours) will be present.